# BXslider removes one item from carousel on loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bxslider

I have a vertical slider with 5 elements showing. If there are only 5 or less items in the carousel I hide the next and previous arrows. If there are more than 6 elements everything works fine, but if I have exactly 6 elements, so one more than I am showing, the BXslider hides one element when I click next and I get to the latest item when it should just loop elements.

I have tried all possible settings but it always hides one element on the last item and than adds one again if I click next again. This seems like a bug in BXslider to me.

here is my code

```
<div id="lead-visual-vertical-carousel">
    <div class="vertical-item">
        <a href="/latest-news">
            <h5>Explore our bakery centre of excellence</h5>
            <p>Rapid product development, test-driving and limited time offers - we can do it all.</p>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="vertical-item">
        <a href="/latest-news">
            <h5>Explore our bakery centre of excellence</h5>
            <p>Rapid product development, test-driving and limited time offers - we can do it all.</p>
        </a>
    </div>    
    <div class="vertical-item">
        <a href="/latest-news">
            <h5>Explore our bakery centre of excellence</h5>
            <p>Rapid product development, test-driving and limited time offers - we can do it all.</p>
        </a>
    </div>    
    <div class="vertical-item">
        <a href="/latest-news">
            <h5>Explore our bakery centre of excellence</h5>
            <p>Rapid product development, test-driving and limited time offers - we can do it all.</p>
        </a>
    </div>   
    <div class="vertical-item">
        <a href="/latest-news">
            <h5>Explore our bakery centre of excellence</h5>
            <p>Rapid product development, test-driving and limited time offers - we can do it all.</p>
        </a>
    </div>    
    <div class="vertical-item">
        <a href="/latest-news">
            <h5>Explore our bakery centre of excellence</h5>
            <p>Rapid product development, test-driving and limited time offers - we can do it all.</p>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and JS code

```
var verticalSlider = $('#lead-visual-vertical-carousel');

verticalSlider.bxSlider({
        mode: 'vertical',
        minSlides: 5,
        maxSlides: 5,
        slideMargin: 0,
        speed: 250,
        infiniteLoop:true,
        moveSlides: 1,
        nextText: '<i class="fa fa-long-arrow-down"></i>',
        prevText: '<i class="fa fa-long-arrow-up"></i>',
        pager: false,
        controls: true,
        adaptiveHeight: false,
        responsive:false,
        onSliderLoad: function () {
            verticalSlider.addClass('slider-loaded');
            $('.bx-controls-direction a').attr('href', '#');
            var total_slide = verticalSlider.getSlideCount();
            if (total_slide < 6) {
                $(".bx-wrapper .bx-controls").hide();
            }
        }
    });
```

I have also added JSfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/om0cn2ew/ here. I havent added all styles so it looks funny but if you click next or previous arrow you can see how the container changes height.